# ASP.NET Core 2: Entity Framework Context is disposed too early in asynchronous PayPal IPN. How do I get it back in a later thread?

Tags: paypal, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an endpoint which is receiving IPN activity from PayPal. Here is the POST Action that is taken straight from their docs with manual modifications:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Receive()
    {
        IPNContext ipnContext = new IPNContext()
        {
            IPNRequest = Request
        };

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ipnContext.IPNRequest.Body, Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            ipnContext.RequestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ipnVarsWithCmd = ipnContext.RequestBody.Split('&')
            .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Split('=')[0], x.Split('=')[1])).ToList();

        //Fire and forget verification task -- ** THIS **
        Task.Run(() => VerifyTask(ipnContext, ipnVarsWithCmd));

        //Reply back a 200 code
        return Ok();
    }
```

The issue is the indicated line. This is a "fire and forget" route, and is executed asynchronously. When the Action is complete, and returns `Ok`, I am assuming that the injected Entity Framework context from the controller:

```
public class IPNController : Controller
{
    private readonly EFContext _context;


    public IPNController(EFContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

... gets Disposed? According to my logs, it looks like it.

Meanwhile, I have that second thread doing the actual legwork of the IPN request which needs that `EFContext` to be around.

Is there a pattern I am missing here? (Bearing in mind whilst I'm not new to .NET I am to .NET Core)

Or is there a way I can "get it back" so I can use it?

---

**Update:**

You might find my initialisation of the context useful:

public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<EFContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    }

}
```

Comment: Fire and forget do not work well in this context because the request and its current scope will be disposed once the request is complete. If the long running task takes too long is will be out of scope and you will get unintended behavior.

Comment: You may need to create another service that is not affect by the scope of a request to handle the background work.

Comment: @Nkosi Yeah, thanks for confirming my suspicions about disposal on a fire-and-forget pattern. Sorted now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
Task.Run(() => VerifyTask(ipnContext, ipnVarsWithCmd));
```

to

```
await Task.Run(() => VerifyTask(ipnContext, ipnVarsWithCmd));
```

and method declaration to:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Receive()
```

Also wrap IPNContext to using block to let it dispose when it is not needed.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. Couldn't see the wood for the trees there. It's late and that was far too obvious!